# How can I fix a run-time error when capturing text from a textbox in a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to capture the value entered into the text box of a form instance which was created using the following module code:

```
Public myForm As Form_Form1    
'Dim myForm As Form_Form1       ' tried this

Sub test()
'Dim myForm As New Form_Form1   ' tried this

Set myForm = New Form_Form1
With myForm
    .Visible = True
'    .SetFocus          ' tried this
'    .Modal = True      ' tried this

    If .IsCancelled Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Debug.Print .RptDt

End With
```

The form is very basic with an OK and Cancel button and a single text box named Text7.  The form code-behind is:

```
Private cancelling As Boolean

Public Property Get RptDt() As String
    RptDt = Text7.Text
End Property

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelling
End Property

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    'DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    Me.Visible = False
    'Me.Visible
End Sub

Private Sub Command4_Click()
    cancelling = True
    'DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    'MsgBox Me.Name
    'MsgBox Me.OpenArgs

    'Me.Hide
    Me.Visible False
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        cancelling = True
    Me.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run the code as is I get:

> "Run-time error '2185' You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus"

I have also tried:

```
 Public Property Get RptDt() As String
    RptDt = Text7.Value
End Property
```

I then get Run-time error '94' Invalid use of null. The code above was modified from a comparable Excel VBA code which uses the Userform Show method (only works in Excel) in the Sub Test() instead of `.Visible = True`.

Comment: Maybe try a `DoEvents` under `.Visible = True`

Comment: Which line is the error firing on?

Comment: The error is being raised at the  
``` Debug.Pring .RptDt``` 
line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a side point, but on the `Command4_Click` event change the below line to add an equals:

```vb
Me.Visible = False
```

This can change the syntax and is a different function to the one intended.

The `.Text` property can only be called when a Control has the focus. Similarly, a `null` exception will be called if you use `.Value` in it's place when the textbox is empty.

There are two ways around this:

**Option 1** - *Handling the NULL value*

```vb
Public Property Get RptDt() As String
    If IsNull(Text7.Text) = True Then
        RptDt = "EmptyString"    'Or whatever string you want to set this to
    Else
        RptDt = Text7.Text
    End if
End Property
```

**Option 2** - *Setting the focus*

```vb
Public Property Get RptDt() As String
    Text7.SetFocus
    RptDt = Text7.Text
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks - good spot. I tried this.  Still doesn't fix the problem.  The error is being thrown by the ```Debug.print .RptDt``` line of code.

Comment: thanks this has fixed the runtime errors, but now unfortunately the code is running all the way through to completion (opening the form, leaving it open) but not pausing to allow the user to enter data in the form before the code finishes.

Comment: happy to uptick your solution on the basis it fixed the issue as outlined.  I can capture the Text7 value but only by declaring a module level variable and then creating another sub to display the value in the now hidden form.  I will do further investigation to try and find a better way.  Really appreciate the assistance